# Slick Carousel add/remove class to body if an slide with class is showed

Tags: jquery, slick.js

This my html markup:

```
<body> 
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide1">
            -- my slide 1 content --
        </div>
        <div class="slide2">
            -- my slide 2 content --
        </div>
        <div class="slide3">
            -- my slide 3 content --
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

How can i add the class 'slide1-current' to body if 'slide1' is showing, then change to 'slide2-current' and at the same time remove 'slide1-current' if 'slide2' is showing and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var slides = jQuery(".slider > div");
  console.log(slides);
  var currentDisplayed = 0;
  var childCount = slides.length;
  $(slides[currentDisplayed]).addClass("slider-current");
  setInterval(function() {
    $(slides[currentDisplayed]).removeClass("slider-current");
    if (currentDisplayed < (childCount - 1)) {
      $(slides[currentDisplayed]).removeClass("slider-current");
      currentDisplayed += 1;
    } else {
      currentDisplayed = 0;
    }
    $(slides[currentDisplayed]).addClass("slider-current");

  }, 1000);

})()
```

```css
.slider-current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1">
    -- my slide 1 content --
  </div>
  <div class="slide2">
    -- my slide 2 content --
  </div>
  <div class="slide3">
    -- my slide 3 content --
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is adding a class to the current slide and slick carousel already do this, the class should be added to body tag and will change depending of the slide name, if current slide has class 'black' so body class should be 'slide-black-showing' if slide has class red so body class should be 'slide-red-showing' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
}).on({
  beforeChange: function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $('body').removeClass('slide' + (currentSlide + 1) + '-current').addClass('slide' + (nextSlide + 1) + '-current')
  }
});
```

```css
.slide1-current {
  color: red;
}
.slide2-current {
  color: green;
}
.slide3-current {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1">-- my slide 1 content --</div>
  <div class="slide2">-- my slide 2 content --</div>
  <div class="slide3">-- my slide 3 content --</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close but the class in the body must be attached to an slide class name, not number, for example, if i have an slide with the classes 'slide1 black' and is the current one class body should change to 'slide-black-showing'.

Comment: Pretty cool! one more thing, this function is running once first slide change, how can i run it once the slider is loaded and before to change the very first slide?

Comment: Yes, did you found a solution? I need this too